# Loops and Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How to loop in a list while using dictionaries and return the value that repeats the most, and if the values are repeated the same amount return that which is greater?
Here some context with code unfinished

```
def most_frequent(lst):
        dict = {}
        count, itm = 0, ''
        for item in lst:
            dict[item] = dict.get(item, 0) + 1
            if dict[item] >= count:
                count, itm = dict[item], item
        return itm
    
    #lst = ["a","b","b","c","a","c"]
    lst = [2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3,1,1,1,1] #this should return 1
    lst2 = [2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3] # should return 3
    print(most_frequent(lst))
```

Comment: What has been the difficulty? What is the problem with the code you have written so far? What is your question about it?

Comment: I know you want to do this with a `dict`, but this may be much easier with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html).

Comment: I think I'm clear enough, the code is not completed since it doesn't return the values I need. I know about collection, but I want to solve without having to import anything. I see this as an opportunity to practice with dictionaries

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You've told us what you want to achieve, and you've shown what you have done, but that doesn't make a question. At the very least, you should explain in what way the code you have shown is lacking.

Comment: And as a side note, it's not much practice if you have the code written for you by others.

Comment: srry man I just think I can also learn to see good code being written since I know I'm a beginner I just like to learn while I see what others write even if it takes time for me to understand what's written that's just a way I like to learn

Comment: I still think is a well explained question, I said what I want to achieve I shared some code where I'm trying to do it but I'm not able to reach the conclusion I want so there is the question I want you guys to help me find that conclusion. How can that not be clear?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: okay now I get it, you posting that link was actually more helpful before I just thought you were being nasty, I get it I was wrong. I'll try to fix the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different way to go about it:

```py
def most_frequent(lst):

    # Simple check to ensure lst has something.
    if not lst:
        return -1

    # Organize your data as: {number: count, ...}
    dct = {}
    for i in lst:
        dct[i] = dct[i] + 1 if i in dct else 1

    # Iterate through your data and create a list of all large elements.
    large_list, large_count = [], 0
    for num, count in dct.items():
        if count > large_count:
            large_count = count
            large_list = [num]
        elif count == large_count:
            large_list.append(num)

    # Return the largest element in the large_list list.
    return max(large_list)
```

There are many other ways to solve this problem, including using `filter` and other built-ins, but this is intended to give you a working solution so that you can start thinking on how to possibly optimize it better.

Things to take out of this; always think:

- How can I break this problem down into smaller parts?
- How can I organize my data so that it is more useful and easier to manipulate?
- What shortcuts can I use along the way to make this function easier/better/faster?

Answer (score 1):

Your code produces the result as you describe in your question, i.e. 1.  However, your question states that you want to consider the case where two list elements are co-equals in maximum occurrence and return the largest.  Therefore, tracking and returning a single element doesn't satisfy this requirement.  You need to compile the dict and then evaluate the result.

```
def most_frequent(lst):
    dict = {}
    for item in lst:
        dict[item] = dict.get(item, 0) + 1

    itm = sorted(dict.items(), key = lambda kv:(-kv[1], -kv[0]))
    return itm[0]

#lst = ["a","b","b","c","a","c"]
lst = [2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3,1,1,1,1] #this should return 1
lst2 = [2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3] # should return 3
print(most_frequent(lst))
```

I edited the list 'lst' so that '1' and '2' both occur 5 times.  The result returned is a tuple:
(2,5)

Comment: wow and I just have to change this line:  dict[item] = dict.get(item, 0) + 1      to    dict[item] = dict.get(item, 0) - 1       if I want to return the number that's less repeated. I'm not familiar with lambda, but I will look into it

Comment: There is no Python problem that you can encounter that hasn't already been solved and written up online.  For 99% of problems, Google will produce a much quicker answer than posing a question in a forum like this.

Comment: why are you using  the -kv[0]? key=lambda kv: (-kv[1], -kv[0]) It's returning the list of tuples with just -kv[1]

Comment: The minus sign in a lambda sort means descending.  You wanted the max occurrence, that is -kv[1].  If the max occurrences is equal, you wanted the largest: that is -kv[0].  Take a look at this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ways-sort-list-dictionaries-values-python-using-lambda-function/

Answer (score 1):

I reuse your idea which is quite neat, and I just modified your program a bit.

```
def get_most_frequent(lst):
    counts = dict()
    most_frequent = (None, 0) # (item, count)

    ITEM_IDX = 0
    COUNT_IDX = 1

    for item in lst:
        counts[item] = counts.get(item, 0) + 1
        if most_frequent[ITEM_IDX] is None:
            # first loop, most_frequent is "None"
            most_frequent = (item, counts[item])
        elif counts[item] > most_frequent[COUNT_IDX]:
            # if current item's "counter" is bigger than the most_frequent's counter
            most_frequent = (item, counts[item])
        elif counts[item] == most_frequent[COUNT_IDX] and item > most_frequent[ITEM_IDX]:
            # if the current item's "counter" is the same as the most_frequent's counter
            most_frequent = (item, counts[item])
        else:
            pass # do nothing
    return most_frequent

lst1 = [2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3,1,1,1,1, 2] # 1: 5 times
lst2 = [2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2] # 3: 3 times
lst3 = [1]
lst4 = []
print(get_most_frequent(lst1))
print(get_most_frequent(lst2))
print(get_most_frequent(lst3))
print(get_most_frequent(lst4))
```